# Cannot fire the DeleteCommand in a Datalist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datalist

I want to fire the Delete Command in Datalist Control .. but it is not firing .. Help please ..

this is my code :

```
protected void DeleteCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
        Label2.Text = "hello";
}
```

and This is my html code :

```
   <asp:DataList ID="DLImages" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
         DataKeyField="fId" RepeatColumns="4" 
         RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" 
         OnDeleteCommand="DeleteCommand" 
         onitemdatabound="DLImages_ItemDataBound">
             <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:ImageButton ID="IBDelete" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Dashboard/Images/dldelete.png" />
             </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like OK to me. It should fire the `DeleteCommand`.

But the problem is that I am sure you are binding the Datalist in your `page_load event`, but not under `If(!IsPostBack) condition.`  What happens when you hit Delete button is your `page_load` event fires before your `DeleteCommand` and it rebinds the `DataList` and your event is lost

Your page_load event code should look like...

```
If(!IsPostBack) 
{
  DataList binding code goes here......
  ...........................
}

protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind the DataList here....
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your page_load event code. If you set breakpoint to your page_load event, and then check on clicking of DeleteComamnd, you will notice that your DataList rebinded in page_load event.

Comment: Dear Muhammad , I have a dropdownlist control and I need to refresh my datalist control when I change the values . but when I set breakpoint in DeleteCommand event , even it can't go into this event .

Comment: and I had to put this code in my html page : EnableEventValidation="false"

Comment: because when I don't put this code in there it shows to me this error : Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Comment: Yes .. you right . it works when I put into (!Ispostback) . But I can't do this .. because I must change datalist items when dropdownlost value changes . I can't do this .. can you help me about this ?